# Multiple Java programs running on the same machine

Tags: java

Ok I just need to understand this thing. I have a JVM installed on my machine. If I develop 2 programs (2 jars with their own main classes) and run them, will they be both running on the same JVM?

If they both run on same JVM instance, how can I make them communicate?

The system I am currently working on has many components installed in one machine but communicate with each other using RMI. Isn't it impractical for these components to use RMI when they are all running on one machine?

Comment: RMI on the same machine is not a problem/issue, it's just remote invocation so it's a good inter-process communication.

Comment: will it be efficient for a Trading Platform where thousands of trades and request for quotes are processed?

Comment: Latency is important to a trading platform, is their a reason you are not using the components *directly* in your program? i.e, include the components as a dependency library (JAR)?

Comment: im new to the project but how i see it is that, the architecture suggests that the components be deployable in other machines (just for flexibility) but all of these are currently just in one machine.. even in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two applications will run in different virutal machines if they are started separately (even if they are running on the same physical machine). OSGi has already been mentioned as a way of bring them together but if you want to maintain them as separate applications it might be worth considering web services as a communication method. The benefit of this over RMI is interoperability with other applications and flexability for future development.

Answer (score 3):

> If I develop 2 programs (2 jars with
>   their own main classes) and run them,
>   will they be both running on the same
>   JVM?

Typically no, each will be run in their own JVM process (`java`), unless you start one from the other in a separate thread or something.

> The system I am currently working on
>   has **many components** installed in one
>   machine but **communicate with each
>   other** using RMI. Isn't it impractical
>   for these components to use RMI when
>   they are **all running on one machine**?

It is sort of impractical, at least inefficient with all the (de)serialization  that takes place. (RMI uses object serialization to marshal and unmarshal parameters)

**OSGi (Dynamic Module System for Java)**

If you are running both locally, and just need components to find each other, I suggest you make them into [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/About/HowOSGi) bundles. It has been engineering for this sort of use.

*(As an example, this is how Eclipse IDE components and plugins interact with each other, while being loosely coupled, and without the unnecessary (de)serialization)*

Comment: I will read OSGi and see if it will be useful in my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you may also use observable pattern if both of the application runs on the same machine - a thought.